# (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17) AND / LIKE operators greyed out

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I'm having issues using `AND` / `LIKE` operators in select queries.

They seem to be **greyed out**, and, for instance, when executing a `SELECT` query that has one or the other, or both included, no records are generated, even though records do exist within the database.

I have tried checking permissions, restarting the database instance - not really sure how to proceed at this point.

Assistance will be greatly appreciated. Many Thanks.

[image: example]

**EDIT:**

Example 1 - As you can see, this query shows two joined tables, which gives me relevant records:

[image: example1]

Example 2 - Once I specify the date using the `AND` Operator, and re-run the query, no records are generated, like none exist. This is the issue I'm experiencing.

[image: example2]

Comment: They're not greyed out, that's just the formatting of SSMS i.e. the syntax highlighting. You can change it. Do you have any records that match your predicate? And how do you know?

Comment: Hi Jim, 

Thank you for your quick reply.

I have posted 2 other screenshots with more details, to help you understand the issue further.

Comment: You might what to add a simpler example in text format to your question instead of images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is not problem that LIKE predicate is grayed, I have this too.
2. You has define a two mutually exclusive conditions in the AND operator in your WHERE predicate - surely this will not work. You need an OR operator between mutually exclusive conditions in your predicate, like

   ```
   WHERE <first predicate>
     AND (Appointment.AppointmentDateTime ='20181102 10:00:00.000' OR 
          Appointment.AppointmentDateTime = '20181105 16:00:00.000')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like the below

```
AND Appointment.AppointmentDateTime
IN ('20181102 10:00:00.000','20181105 16:00:00,000')
```

and if you're looking for a range you can use:

```
AND Appointment.AppointmentDateTime
BETWEEN '20181102 10:00:00.000' AND '20181105 16:00:00,000'
```

You're currently asking for one record with two AppointmentDateTime values, which is of course impossible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help - it worked, however, can you kindly assist in the below case, please?

I was initially using 'AND','>' & '<' to specify two dates.

Comment: Have edited the answer. You should have a look into IN, AND, OR, EXISTS, BETWEEN, and IIF keywords on Microsoft books online.

Comment: Ignore my above comment please.

Thanks a lot for the help - it worked, however, can you kindly assist in the below case, please?

I was initially using 'AND' Operator to specify two dates.

Taking into consideration the Example 1 screenshot above, there are 10 appointments, but I want to specify appointments done between two dates.

What I tried doing in the Example 2 screenshot is as described above - I wanted to get Appointments that are between '2018-11-02 10:00:00.000' and '2018-11-05 16:00:00.000'.

Not sure how to specify that.

Comment: Why can't you use between like in my answer? Does that not work for you?

Comment: Perfect, the range is what I was looking for - didn't know about 'Between' operator - And apologies, just saw it now.

The query I required worked.

Appreciate the help from you Jim, and the rest.

Kind Regards

Comment: Lovely. Glad i could help. Can you kindly mark mine as the answer please?